# How to write RewriteRule for login in multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect, login

In my wp multisite mysite.com, I want any login request to be sent to my custom login page at mysite.com/login.
I found this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/login/$ http://mysite.com/login/ [L]
```

It works, but it does not send the user back to the previous page after login. The previous page could be on mysite.com or mysite.com/subsite1.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I built a multisite, mysite.com composed of mysite.com/subsite1, mysite.com/subsite2... and use Theme my Login plugin.
As I wanted all the login requests to be sent to mysite.com/login, I found a rewrite rule to acheive that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/login/$ http://mysite.com/login/ [L,QSA,NE]
```

Basically, after my readings and anderstanding, this `^(.*)/` will find any url with 'login' in mysite.com and subsites, and redirect it to mysite.com/login.
Explaining the flags from: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html:

> "The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed."
>   "With the [QSA] flag, a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped to /page.php?page=123&one=two. Without the [QSA] flag, that same request will be mapped to /page.php?page=123 - that is, the existing query string will be discarded."
>   "Using the [NE] flag prevents (special characters, such as & and ?, for example, from being converted to their hexcode equivalent. 
>   RewriteRule ^/anchor/(.+) /bigpage.html#$1 [NE,R]. This example will redirect /anchor/xyz to /bigpage.html#xyz. Omitting the [NE] will result in the # being converted to its hexcode equivalent, %23, which will then result in a 404 Not Found error condition."

The combination of those rules will send a user to mysite.com/login, then redirect them to the previous page after login.

I hope my explanation is helpful -;)

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: @toscho, please refer to the problem I faced above.

Comment: I know what the difference does, but you should explain it for other readers not familiar with rewrite flags.

Comment: Hi @toscho, sorry for my late feedback. I´m very new to php and wordpress. Here´s a link for the flags: [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html]

Comment: Please update _your answer_: Explain what you changed and why it solved the problem. Links are useful, but an answer should not rely on it. :)